# Print caught Exception type without printing the error description

Tags: python, error-handling, valueerror

I'm making a simple calculator program for a class project. I have an `Exception` handler that catches errors and returns the error `type`. Though whenever it catches an `Exception`, it prints the error `type` along with its description. Is there a way to only have it print the error `type`?

Code:

```
operations = ('Add', 'Subtract', 'Multiply', 'Divide')
def insigStrip(flt):
    if str(flt)[-1] == '0':
        return int(flt)
    return flt
def main():
    print('Select operation:')
    for i in range(len(operations)):
        print(str(i+1) + ':', operations[i])
    while True:
        try:
            option = int(input('Enter choice(1/2/3/4): '))
            if option in range(len(operations) + 1):
                x = insigStrip(float(input('Enter first number: ')))
                n = insigStrip(float(input('Enter second number: ')))
                if option == 1:
                    print(x, '+', n, '=', insigStrip(x+n))
                if option == 2:
                    print(x, '-', n, '=', insigStrip(x-n))
                if option == 3:
                    print(x, '*', n, '=', insigStrip(x*n))
                if option == 4:
                    try:
                        print(x, '/', n, '=', insigStrip(x/n))
                    except ZeroDivisionError:
                        print('Cannot divide by Zero.')
                break
            else:
                print('Invalid input.')
                continue
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error caught:', repr(e))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For `x` or `n`, it only accepts 1, 2, 3, or 4 as input. Say for example, I were to input t for `x`. This would raise a `ValueError`. The `try except` statement inside the `while` loop then catches said `ValueError` and prints out `Error caught: type(error)`.

Desired Output:

```
>>> t
Error caught: ValueError
```

Given output:

```
>>> t
Error caught: <class 'ValueError'> (if type(e))
```

or:

```
>>> t
Error caught: ValueError: insert error description (if repr(e))
```

How do I get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the caught `Exception`'s type **name** like this:

```
except Exception as e:
    print('Error caught:', type(e).__name__)
```